# crypt() in MinGW

Tags: c, mingw

How can I use crypt() on Windows compiling with MinGW? I see that it has the lib but it doesn't recognize the function and crypt.h header, and if I use windows.h I get a bunch of mistakes like 'unknown type name BOOL', 'unknown type name DWORD' etc.

Comment: Where in your MinGW folder is the crypt.h?

Comment: `crypt.h` will just have function declarations. The function definitions will be inside the .lib (or .dll). Are you sure you're linking the .lib file as well? Easiest way (IMHO) to link would be to use `#pragma comment()`. Additionally, if all this doesn't work, would you mind trying [wincrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx)?

Comment: It looks like I should additionally compile crypt(3) for MinGW even having the full package installed, but when i try it gives a weird shell error... i just found pretty cleaned cross-platform crypt(3) source code here http://michael.dipperstein.com/crypt/index.html and used it. you can close the question, anyway you like to do it for any reason. anish ram, thanks for the link but i don't want to encrypt something, i just need the same output which linux crypt() does